# RequireJS - Return content of lazy load static file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am writing an util module, which contains a function that lazy load a json file and return the content, but I can't seem to get this working...

```
define([
  'require'
], function (require) {
  var util = {
    jsonData: [],

    getJsonData: function () {
      require(['require', 'text!dummyData.json'], _.bind(function (require) {
        this.jsonData.concat(JSON.parse(require('text!dummyData.json')));
      }, this));
      return this.jsonData;
    }
  };
  return util;
});
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are trying (and failing) to `return` something from an *asynchronous* function. All calls to `require` that have a list of dependencies as the first argument are asynchronous. If you call `require` like this in a function of yours and your function is meant to provide back results that depend on this `require` call, then your function is *also* asynchronous.

You need something like the following code where `getJsonData` accepts a callback and calls it once it has the data. I've also changed `require('text!text!dummyData.json')` to remove one of the `text!` prefixes, which has no business there.

```
define([
  'require'
], function (require) {
  var util = {
    jsonData: [],

    getJsonData: function (callback) {
      require(['require', 'text!dummyData.json'], _.bind(function (require) {
        this.jsonData.concat(JSON.parse(require('text!dummyData.json')));
        callback(this.jsonData);
      }, this));
    }
  };
  return util;
});
```